# How to call main page after Facebook login on my web application

Tags: java, facebook

I'm building a web application using Google app engine and google web tools.
I have tried to implement Facebook login page using html.
So I have my own login and registration system, and also the Facebook login system.
The problem is,
Once a person is logged in thru Facebook, it just stays in the main login page,
When I want it to go to the main page. 
I have to put some code to direct to main page, but I don't know where to put on html.

```
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : 'This is where My App ID was...', // App ID
        channelUrl : '//www.Icannnotshowyou.com/', // Channel File
        status     : true, // check login status
        cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
      });

      //put something here?

    });

    };
    // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function(d){
       var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
       if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
       js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
       ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
     }(document));
  </script>
<div class="fb-login-button">Login with Facebook</div>
</body>
</center>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you must have set the callback url while creating the facebook app which should redirect you back to that url which in my case was a servlet that did all the processing on the graph object and then i returned a string back in response which was processed by a js function which was embedded in my html head tag. And further using this string i redirected call to other page.